# Receiving Microsoft date format in json

Tags: android, date, datetime, kotlin, datetime-format

I am using Kotlin and somehow I'm receiving this weird type of date format i had never ever seen before:

```
/Date(1224043200000)/
```

What is this format, and how can we display the date using this?  I have been using Json ISO standard 8601. And I know how to convert it's format to date but this one is new for me.

Answer (score 1):

`1224043200000` refers to the number of milliseconds from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` and is equivalent to `2008-10-15T04:00:00Z` at UTC.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1224043200000L);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Get ZonedDateTime from Instant
        // I have used time-zone of Europe/London. Use a time-zone as per your
        // requirement. You can also use ZoneId.systemDefault()
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

        // Get OffsetDateTime from ZonedDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();

        // Get LocalDateTime from ZonedDateTime if required. However, note that
        // LocalDateTime drops the valuable information, time-zone from ZonedDateTime
        // and zone-offset from OffsetDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2008-10-15T04:00:00Z
2008-10-15T05:00
```

**Backport of the Java SE 8 date-time classes to Java SE 6 and 7:**

Check [ThreeTen-Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [How to use ThreeTenABP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

Comment: But can u please tell me whether we should use this type of old json? Coz i searched and people said that it's bad to use this for new development? We should use json ISO 8601 instead.

Comment: Correct, ISO 8601 is preferred.

Comment: Thank you, this works but only in api level >= 26

Comment: @Aldor - I've added the links at the end about how you can backport this to Java SE 6 and 7. I suggest you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Comment: okay thanks for helping me out!